# Does a column exist in SharePoint that shows permissioned users?

Tags: 2013, permissions, document

We have a library that we are using for sales commissions approval.  Each document has unique permissions (approver and commission recipient).  Is there a column that can be added that would show all users that have been permissioned to the document.  The only way I can check now is clicking on ellipsis and "Share With".  We have had some issues with it being shared improperly and it would be great to have visibility.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The Shared with column by design is not available or inherited into the Sharepoint List, Item level sharing is new but shares the same concept like a document library, unfortunately as usual Microsoft have this as a half baked product too.

i am currently testing using the Audience targeting feature available and then making the Audience column visible

Answer (score -1):

From List Settings -> Modify View and Select field "Shared With"

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I don't have a "Shared With" field in my library.  Do I need to configure it somewhere?

Comment: @Darcie once you use the Shared With feature this field will appear in the View Settings page

Comment: Thanks Amal.. I'm hoping I'm just missing something.  I "Shared" a document and a permission restricted library.  I then went into Library Settings/Columns.  I still do not have a "Shared With" column available.  We are using SharePoint 2013 (not sure if it matters). Thanks again.

Comment: It will get listed under the View Settings page.. You won't find it under List Settings

Comment: This answer is confusing.

Comment: I don't see a View Settings page.  I can modify my view...

Comment: When you modify view can you see the field I mentioned?

Comment: It does not exist when I modify view.  Appreciate you help.